# Increase download speed of ftp server

Tags: performance, ftp, network-speed, vsftpd

I have a VSFTPD server running in my machine. The download speed is about 30 KB/s, which is way less than my connection speed. I understand the upload speed of the server affects the download speed on the client.

However the download speed is only 30 KB/s, is there any setting in VSFTPD to increase the download speed?

Comment: You can use [Download Calculator](https://downloadtime.org) from downloadtime to find the exact download time for a file. This will help you give an exact estimation. Sometimes it might be the major issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no FTP server that, by default, imposes download speed restrictions.

This is likely due to a congested (or slow) path somewhere between your client and the server. As such, there's likely very little you can do about it.

Comment: +1 or an ISP that castrates server-type traffic. Common with certain Large ISPs.

Comment: or bad TCP window size (missing scaling) on client or server if it's a high bandwidth, high latency link in between.

Answer (score 0):

How far apart geographically is the client for the server? You can try to run the PING command from the client to the server to see how much latency there is on the line in milliseconds. Anything over 100ms will affect your speed.

Network latency will greatly reduce your optimal FTP throughput.

There are file transfer tools that can help with the latency issue. 
Take a look at UFTP http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net (free open source)

or

FileCatalyst http://www.filecatalyst.com on a non-free commercial software side.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the QOS configuration in the network, if FTP traffic is being treated at less priority.

Another possibility is if packet inspection is enabled on firewall for ftp traffic (assuming there is one between clients and server)

In any case, it is advisable to involve the network guys to check it, they may be able to find the bottleneck.